# routerLink not navigating to a new page

Tags: angular

My app doesn't navigate to a new page so from googling, I found out that I am supposed to import RouterModule (which is where RouterLink is declared) into the module which uses this template.

I get the error:  Two incompatible decorators on class @NgModule

error The class 'ShoppingCartComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

In shopping-cart.component.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule(
{
   imports:[
       RouterModule
   ]
}
)
public checkOut(): void {

this.router.navigate(['/check-out'], {relativeTo: this.route});

//this.router.navigateByUrl('/check-out/check-out');
}
```

In app-routing.module.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CheckOutComponent } from './check-out/check-out.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{
   path: 'check-out',
   component: CheckOutComponent
   }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})


export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In app.module.ts

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CheckOutComponent } from './check-out/check-out.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CheckOutComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
     RouterModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }


constructor(public router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

shopping-cart.component.html

```
<form>

<a [routerLink]="'/check-out'"><button (click)="checkOut()" type="submit"> Check Out</button></a>

</form>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `@NgModule` decorator in your *shopping-cart.component.ts*? Components need a `@Component` decorator. Read the docs on routing: https://angular.io/guide/router.

Comment: There is no module which uses this template. It's a component, not a module.

Comment: **app.module.ts** uses your _shopping-cart.component.ts_

Comment: Yes app.module.ts imports my shopping-cart.component I just forgot to add it to my question.

Answer (score 1):

ShoppingCartComponent is not a component, it is decorated as a module. You cannot list modules in the declarations array of another module. You must import modules into the imports array.

Angular apps are Single Page Applications, so all components will load in the main router outlet. Now, of course you can have multiple nested router outlets. You should typically use the App Component as the top level of the application where the app's chrome (main menu, logo, sign out, etc.) is located.

Your shopping cart component should then be placed in its own module. Within the ShoppingCartModule, you should import a new ShoppingCartRoutingModule. You could place an additional router outlet in the ShoppingCartComponent and then add child routes to the ShoppingCartComponent. Regardless, all of the components ultimately be part of the main router outlet.

Here is a link to a StackBlitz project that shows how you can refactor your application using dedicated modules and router modules for the different parts of the application.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbundf?file=src/app/app.module.ts

If you navigate to `https://angular-ivy-bbundf.stackblitz.io/cart` you will see that the ShoppingCartComponent loads in the main router outlet. You will also see in the ShoppingCartComponent that it has its own router outlet as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I removed @NgModule(
{
   imports:[
       RouterModule
   ]
}
)and now it doesn't navigate to the route but the error messages go away.

Comment: When I put <router-outlet></router-outlet> in my app.component.html it displays the route so I know that it is navigating to the right url but I don't want to show the page inside of the component. I want to navigate to a new page.

Comment: I tried the stackblitz but it loads the page in the same page. I need to navigate to a new page for my check-out component.

Comment: It's always going to load in the same page. Angular is for single page apps. To achieve what you want, you need to move the app chrome to a component other than the AppComponent. That requires a more complicated design structure, as your login/logout, main menu, etc. might need to be repeated throughout the app.